# HighCharts x-axis & y-axis label center align

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

```
chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotBox.x,                      
                            chart.plotBox.y, width, height, 1)
            .attr({
                fill: 'white',
                zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();
```

We created four quadrants in Highcharts using the above mentioned code similar to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEySL/), but we want the labels for the x-axis and y-axis to display as shown here: http://www.mathcats.com/crafts/grids/4quadrantgrid.html

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `offset` attribute to move your axis. [Documentation here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset).

[Your Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fEySL/590/) with axis in the center.

Comment: Kabulan0lak that was helpful but I wanted to show the section as -20,-40 on both x and y axis as well with offset only the end points i.e 100 is set have achieved it by setting tickInterval:2